# QGraphicsWidget as a child of QObject

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicswidget

is this possible to have a tree-like structure of QObjects and (for example) QGraphicsWidgets ? I mean, I cannot write initialization Lists like these:

```
class MyButton : public QGraphicsWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyButton(int buttonId, QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent)
    {
    }
```

and then, be like

```
myButton = new MyButton(id, myObject);
```

Should I do .setParent or what ?

Update: see actual assignment:

```
class myObject : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyObject(QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {
        }

    MyButton *myButton;

    void showButton(){
        myButton = new MyButton(id, this); //no matching function for call to 'MyButton::MyButton(MyObject* const)'
//note:   no known conversion for argument from 'MyObject* const' to 'QGraphicsObject*'
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing `parent` as in QObject parent/child hierarchy parent and `parent item` in the graphics scene. If you want the former, you do need to use the usual `setParent` mechanism.

Either way, that base class construction attempt is wrong. Replace it with this:

```
MyButton(int buttonId, QGraphicsItem *parent = 0) : QGraphicsWidget(parent)
```

Futhermore, if you use Qt 5, you may wish to check out`Q_NULLPTR` instead of `0`, `NULL`, `nullptr` and other variants.

If you want graphics items to be parents, then you will need to use `QGraphicsObject`s that inherit both `QGraphicsItem` and `QObject`. They can be used for both parenting purposes.

Also, since `QGraphicsWidget` inherits `QGraphicsObject`, it can be directly for both parenting mechanisms.

Comment: no, I just hoped for some workaround before marking your answer. But probably you are right, there is no way of building such hierarchy

Comment: @DensiTensy: there is, setParent as written in the answer. :)